# I have my server running on terminal but unable to access tomcat8 homepage on browser

Tags: java, tomcat8, ubuntu-15.04

I have running my tomcat8 server on gnome-ubuntu 15.04 but dont know on which port.I read a tutorial which says something about firewall setting...please help

Comment: Have you tried the default port `8080`?

Comment: yes...but it says unable to connect to server

Comment: If you installed it with `apt-get` (or even if you didn't) that's the default port. If the server isn't responding, it probably isn't running.

Comment: port 8080 is not being listened but when start server it says server started

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know on which port is Tomcat listening, you have to open `server.xml` file and seek for HTTP connector (*The connector whose `protocol` attribute is `HTTP/1.1`*). You will find something like this:

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
    connectionTimeout="20000"
    redirectPort="8443" />
```

In that connector, `port` attribute is what you are looking for

If you installed Tomcat 8 from Ubuntu app repository, then you will find `server.xml` in `/etc/tomcat8/server.xml`. If you installed from tarball you will find it inside `conf` directory.